# the osculating planes of a curve pass through a fixed point $\rightarrow$ the curve is a plane curve.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

If the osculating planes of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is a plane curve.

How to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametrize the curve by arclength, as usual, by $\alpha(s)$. Say the fixed point is the origin. Then there are functions $a(s)$ and $b(s)$ so that $$\alpha(s) = a(s)\mathbf T(s) + b(s)\mathbf N(s).$$
Now differentiate and apply Frenet.

Comment: Can we say the fixed point is the origin without loss of generality? I don't see how...

Comment: @Pthrp97  If all the planes pass through $\mathbf a$, just subtract that vector from $\alpha(s)$ and proceed.

Comment: How do you know $\alpha(s)$ is alredy a combination of $T$ and $N$? Is $\alpha$ the curve or the point?

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín As I indicated in the answer, the osculating plane at $\alpha(s)$ passes through the origin, so $\alpha(s)$ is (the negative of) some linear combination of $T(s)$ and $N(s)$.

Comment: Because $\alpha(s)$ is the point the plane and the curve have in common?? Thank you for the response to an old answer.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín The osculating plane is $\{\alpha(s)+uN(s)+vB(s): u,v\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: I  see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes upon derivation, you should tao go to 0. Note that there is no B term. so the N' term will have a $\tau$ $\vec{B}$ term but this will go to zero.