# If all the osculating planes of a curve pass through a fixed point, the curve is a plane curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha\colon I\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular curve parametrized by arc length, such as $\kappa (s)>0,\,\forall s\in I$. Show that: if all the osculating planes of $\alpha$ pass through a fixed point, then $\alpha$ is a plane curve.

My attempt:

We know the osculating plane is normal to the binormal vector B(s).

Let $R(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the common intersection of the osculating planes. Then the equation of the osculating plane at any point $P(a,b,c)$ of the curve is given by
$$\langle(R-P),B(s)\rangle=0, \,\forall s\in I$$
Differentiating, we get
\begin{align}
\langle(R-P)',B(s)\rangle+\langle(R-P),B'(s)\rangle &=0\\
\langle(R-P),B'(s)\rangle &=0\\
\langle(R-P),\tau(s)N(s)\rangle &=0.
\end{align}

Now, suppose $\alpha$ is not a plane curve, that is, $\tau \neq 0$. Thus, we have $\langle(R-P),N(s)\rangle =0$, that is, $(R-P)$ is orthogonal to $N(s)$. But also, $\langle(R-P),B(s)\rangle=0$, hence $(R-P)$ is paralell to $T(s)$.

However, I don't see how I can conclude the proof from there. What should I do next? Also, is my writing correct?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the osculating planes of a curve pass through a fixed point $\rightarrow$ the curve is a plane curve.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369378/the-osculating-planes-of-a-curve-pass-through-a-fixed-point-rightarrow-the-cu)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think my approach is different. I'm not sure how I can prove it in the way mentioned in that answer, so I tried in a different way that made more sense to me.

Comment: $P$ is also a function of $s$, so I'm not sure how you get $\langle ((R-P)',B(s)\rangle = 0$.